# Copy all the tables from MS Access(.mdb) to another MS Access(.mdb) at once (Structure Only)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

How to copy all the tables(global and local) from one MS Access file(.mdb) to another MS Access file(.mdb) with structure only. The MS Access file is linked with SQL server. If I try export option in MS Access, it creates a link table which I don't want. Is there any code in VBA to copy all the tables at once and paste only the structure of tables to another MS Access file ?

Comment: Do you want to create (empty) local tables from the linked SQL Server tables?

Comment: Yes, I want to create empty local tables from MS Access linked with MS SQL Server.

Comment: Oh. This is completely different from a "copy", it is a full migration. Please edit your question accordingly. But it is probably off-topic - too broad or "find a tool".

Answer (score 0):

Open the target database and go to *External Data*.

Click *Access*, select the source file, and mark *Import tables etc.* and click *OK*.

Select tab *Tables*, click *Select All*, and click *Settings >>*.

Under *Import Tables* mark *Definition only*. Click *OK*.

Comment: Hi Gustav. Thanks for the help! This works well for local tables. But for the tables in SQL server, it creates link for the tables. Can you please suggest how can I get local table and **not the link** in target database.

Comment: Oh, that seems to be a $$-task: [SQL Server to Access database migration](https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/howto/sql-to-access). Or check out [Exporting-Data-from-SQL-to-Access-in-Mdb-File](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13128/Exporting-Data-from-SQL-to-Access-in-Mdb-File) at CodePlex.